# What's the size of the last Ripple ledger and the indices to search through it?

Tags: ripple, storage, ripple-ledger

What is the size of the current ledger and all indices required to efficiently search through it or query it? Also, how will this size grow relative to the number of Ripple users?

Side-question: what database technology is used by rippled to store the ledger?

Answer (score 3):

Ledger 8470000 in JSON format (without inner nodes) is 115 MB large. You can get it if you issue the "ledger" API call on a rippled that you own - it's an admin-only call, as it takes lots of ressources to assemble it.

If you are asking about the size of the databases rippled uses in the backend, these are about 9 GB (ledger headers + validations archive) ~100 GB (transactions) and ~320GB (RocksDB node store, snappy compression enabled) on my node.

Rippled can utilize several backends, the most mature/recommended is RocksDB, a LevelDB adaption by facebook. In general rippled just needs a high performance key-value store for the largest chunk of data (nodes), transactions and other stuff is stored in SQLite databases.

Comment: Are those values for the latest ledger only? In rippled you have the option to not store historical data, but only the current ledger (balances and outstanding offers, but no transactions).

Comment: These values are for running a rippled server with full history (= it'll try to get as much history as possible, down to eventually ledger 32570). I am not aware of a setting that tells rippled to not store transactions.

If you set rippled to not fetch full history (by default it'll fetch just 256 ledgers back) it will store the ledger number it saw when starting up, fetch backwards until it reaches $startup_ledger - the number set there and then keep on storing data, until you delete everything and restart, this changing the starting point.

Comment: https://github.com/ripple/rippled/blob/develop/doc/rippled-example.cfg#L496

Comment: This will still fetch and store transactions from the past (up to the configured depth) and store all future transactions from the time it connects to other servers.